# Flutter web sometimes doesn't run in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, google-chrome, debugging, flutter-web

I am using visual studio for my flutter project and sometimes it doesn't work when I try to debug. Here are the details

**VS Code**

[image]

**[image: What I get in Console]**

**What I see on chrome**

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? This is my launch.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Dart & Flutter",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "debug"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Update** -
It runs from the command line by this command - `flutter run -d chrome` but then the hot reload doesn't work. How can I attach a debugger to an already running instance?

Comment: Try to add this to configuration (port is optional but I use it this way so that it does not change): `"args":["-d", "chrome", "--web-port=51975"]`.

Comment: where in Launch.json?

Comment: within `configurationa`, under `flutterMode` for example

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. But I was getting the same issue with the android studio as well. Where to set this setting in android studio?

Comment: I don't use Android Studio.